# On click image change (pause and play button)

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm setting up a 3d audio player in A-Frame and am having trouble with The pause and play button images changing depending on if the audio is playing or not

[Here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/boggy-carrot) is a link to my code in action.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** NOT a third party site.  [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing attributes od DOM elements, use

```
el.setAttribute('src', newSrc)
```

instead of

```
el.src = newSrc
```

working glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-56503714?path=script.js:33:42).